# How to get in touch with Stack Exchange moderators?

Tags: support, stackexchange

We would like to get in touch with SE moderators, to try to promote our space out of beta, but it has proven more difficult than expected.

Anyone more familiar with the SE space, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I have taken the matter up in the [teachers lounge chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge).

> Cardano SE is eligible for transition out of Beta status. Is there a
> defined process or do we need to contact a CM or a specific CM?

It is where experienced mods are on hand to discuss moderator questions.

---

**Update**

Response from the chat was that there is no 'defined' process at present, just ping a CM and ask.

*Note:* Typing `whois cm` in the Teachers lounge chat will return a list of CMs and which ones are currently in the chat.

Comment: Will update if/when I have a response, but my timezone doesn't help.

Comment: Doesn't Cardano.SE have a private chat room only for diamond mods? Matter Modeling has a room like that.

Comment: Yes we do, but we had trouble getting their attention.  Not sure whether it was my weird timezone or CM's personal issues that meant we didn't get a response in chat.  It seems that the better way to get their attention is by flagging a post in Cardano meta.  See my other answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Moderators can tag posts in Meta with the moderator-only tag [status-review](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review)

That will get the attention of Community Managers (CMs).